# Use BE provided Enum in FE is possible and how?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-material

I have this Enum from BE  , I want to use it on HTML template , I can use this and how ? or I should provide another one in FE too , what is best practice in this case ?

```
export interface UserModel { 
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    password?: string;
    gender?: UserModel.GenderEnum;
    createdAt?: Date;
    deletedAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
} 

export namespace UserModel {
    export type GenderEnum = 'male' | 'female';
    export const GenderEnum = {
        Male: 'male' as GenderEnum,
        Female: 'female' as GenderEnum
    }; 
}
```

I don't know what should I put on ?????? in below FE code :

```
   <mat-radio-group class="radio-group" id="gender" formControlName="gender"  required>
          <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" [checked]="user.gender === ?????" value="1">{{'user.male' | translate}}</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" [checked]="user.gender === ?????" value="0">{{'user.female' | translate}}</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: In your component define a variable genderEnum = Usermodel.GenderEnum. Then you can use genderEnum.MALE in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** : I defined a variable as below in the ts file and easily could use it on the HTML

```
genderEnum = Usermodel.GenderEnum
```